# Issue with stubbing/mocking the method with makes a DB call

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, mockito

I am having issue with Mocking a JDBC call using the MockitoJUnitRunner. 
Somehow Mockito is not mocking the actual call even though I have below subbing line into the test class.

```
when(readOnlyJdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), any(Object[].class), any(int[].class), any(FeatureCollectionResponseExtractor.class))).thenReturn(actual);
```

Very similar mocking is working in another class for very similar type of method. The only difference between them is my other class does have 3 parameters instead of 4 parameters. Below is the code which is actually mocking successfully for different class.

```
when(readOnlyJdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), any(Object[].class), any(FeaturesResultExtractor.class))).thenReturn(actual);
```

Below is my actual code.

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.sql.Types;

import static com.accounts.features.utils.Constants.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;

@Profile
@Log
@Named("featureLibraryDao")
public class FeatureLibraryDaoImpl implements FeatureLibraryDao {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(FeatureLibraryDaoImpl.class);

    @Value("${feature.library.function.sql.query}")
    private String sqlSelectQuery;

    @Inject
    @Named("readOnlyJdbcTemplate")
    private JdbcTemplate readOnlyJdbcTemplate;

    @Override
    public FeatureCollectionDTO getFeaturesData(FeatureRequest request) {
        try {
            int[] argTypes = new int[] { Types.BIGINT, Types.VARCHAR, Types.SMALLINT};
            return readOnlyJdbcTemplate.query(sqlSelectQuery, new Object[] {
                        Long.parseLong(request.getAccountId()), request.getRequestedFeatures(), request.getApplicationSuffix()
                    }, argTypes,
                    new FeatureCollectionResponseExtractor(request));
        } catch (CustomException cbe) {
            throw cbe;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOGGER.error("getFeaturesData method failed with error message:{}", ex.getMessage(), ex);

            CustomErrorCode error = new CustomErrorCode(INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            error.setDeveloperText(ex.getMessage());
            throw new CustomSystemException(error, HttpURLConnection.HTTP_INTERNAL_ERROR);
        }
    }

}
```

and below is my test class.

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class FeatureLibraryDaoImplTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private FeatureLibraryDaoImpl dao;

    @Mock
    private JdbcTemplate readOnlyJdbcTemplate;

    private List<String> features = Arrays.asList("excl_clsd_ind_only", "excl_chrgoff_ind_only", "excl_dsput_ind_only");

    @Test
    public void getFeaturesDataWhenSuccess() {
        //given
        FeatureRequest request = getFeatureRequest();
        FeatureCollectionDTO actual = new FeatureCollectionDTO(features);

        when(readOnlyJdbcTemplate.query(anyString(), any(Object[].class), any(int[].class), any(FeatureCollectionResponseExtractor.class))).thenReturn(actual);

        //when
        FeatureCollectionDTO dto = dao.getFeaturesData(request);

        //then
        assertThat(dto, notNullValue());
    }
}
```

Any suggestion about what is wrong here? Is there any issue with `any(int[].class)` ?

Comment: does it return `null` or any error message ?

Comment: yes it returns null

Comment: Have you tried `any()` for your arguments to check if the types are all fine? Also check the invocations registered on the mock `new org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil().getMockHandler(readOnlyJdbcTemplate).getInvocationContainer().getInvocations()`

Comment: @Deadpool If the mock weren't injected, then should OP get an NPE?

Comment: I think i found the issue can you please try `isNull()` in place of `anyString()` first argument @user3452558

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do see you are not passing the sql query `sqlSelectQuery` value during the test case, But during mock you specified `anyString()` so it must be some value but not null. Since you are using `spring` project, you can use `ReflectionTestUtils` to set the field value for object

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    ReflectionTestUtils.setField(dao, "sqlSelectQuery", "query");

}
```

Comment: Thanks Deadpool..!!

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys thanks much for all your suggestions. So I found that Test code is perfectly fine. Some how `@Value` tag wasn't injecting the actual value the `sqlSelectQuery` in the main code file.
`@Value("${feature.library.function.sql.query}") private String sqlSelectQuery;`

Instead of that I changed code to `private String sqlSelectQuery = "${feature.library.function.sql.query}"` and all test cases are passing.

Somehow `sqlSelectQuery` was't getting the value and hence Mockito wasn't mocking the actual method call. I am yet reviewing why `@value` is not working as it should be.

Comment: The reason is that `mockito` has no relation to the `@value` annotation. Hence its ignored. You'll either need to use something that at this context so it can be resolved or as `Deadpool` suggested you need to set a value manuelly.